# How to include data type validation on state - React Functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm been start using React Functional components. I have a doubt, how I can validate and avoid for specific state update with a wrong data type...

I have the following Hook:

```
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({
    idProjectHeader: 0,
    projectName: "",
    isActive: false,
    idMethodology: 0,
    idUser: 0
});
```

When I trying to use in the render method I do:

```
<input
        id='methodology'
        placeholder='Select a methodology'
        value={apiData.idMethodology}
        onChange={e => setApiData({ ...apiData, idMethodology: e.target.value })}
    />
```

But I have the following warning:

> "message": "Argument of type '{ idMethodology: string; idProjectHeader: number; >projectName: string; isActive: boolean; idUser: number; }' is not assignable to >parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ idProjectHeader: number; projectName: >string; isActive: boolean; idMethodology: number; idUser: number; }>'.
>
> Type '{ idMethodology: string; idProjectHeader: number; projectName: string; >isActive: boolean; idUser: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ >idProjectHeader: number; projectName: string; isActive: boolean; idMethodology: >number; idUser: number; }'.

Types of property 'idMethodology' are incompatible.

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'."

---

Exists a way to validate this in a easy, standard way?

And... sorry to include this question right here... but, is correct update the state in that way? Exists another method?

Comment: [I am not able to reproduce this..](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/qePZRo?editors=1011) can you provide some pseudo code that shows this error?

Comment: you use typescript ?

Comment: @RichWarrior: Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only want to allow number inputs for `idMethodology`. If that's the case, you can add `type="number"` to the input, and make sure you set `idMethodology` to a number, instead of the string contained in `e.target.value`:

```
    <input
        id='methodology'
        type="number"
        placeholder='Select a methodology'
        value={apiData.idMethodology}
        onChange={e => setApiData({ ...apiData, idMethodology: parseInt(e.target.value) })}
    />
```

Comment: Looks promising, but, not will help me to validate Dates or Floats... in that case PropTypes helps a lot... there is any chance to validate those cases?

Answer (score 1):

1 Are you using typescript.

2 You get an error message because the type is e.target.value string.

3 For everything to work you must convert the string to a number.

```
  <input
    id="methodology"
    placeholder="Select a methodology"
    value={apiData.idMethodology}
    onChange={e =>
      setApiData({ ...apiData, idMethodology: +e.target.value })
    }
```

But be careful! if you enter an input that is different from the number, get NaN .